# mysql query doesn't work inside loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have written this code`

```
$serial_no = 1; 
while($rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery))
echo $rowss['work_date'];
$mauzaNameQry = mysqli_query($conn,"select moza_name from moza_names where          mauza_id =1");
echo mysql_error();
$mauzaNameRslt = mysqli_fetch_array($mauzaNameQry);
`echo $rowss['work_date'];
`
```

it does not return me anything in $rowss[] array when I write another query of select inside loop as I have written above select query inside while loop which selects data from moza_name table. $rowss[] shows data if I remove inside query of moza_name table. It even doesn't show any error's.

Comment: you would need 2 different connection objects

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on your problem ? What exactly does not work and what are you expecting ?

Comment: this doesn't help you `echo mysql_error();` add the `i` and db connection to it - read the manual, it says so http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php . Plus, we don't know what the query above that does, mainly for `$selectQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but this may be it?

```
<?php
    $serial_no = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)) {
        echo $row['work_date'];
    }
    $mauzaNameQry = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT moza_name FROM moza_names WEHRE `mauza_id`='1'") or die(mysqli_error($mauzaNameQry));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mauzaNameQry)) {
        echo $row['work_date'];
    }
?>
```

UPDATE:

Are you trying to do a nested loop?

```
    <?php
    $serial_no = 1; 
    while($rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)) {
    echo $rowss['work_date'];
        $mauzaNameQry = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT moza_name FROM moza_names where `mauza_id`='1'") or die();
        while($mauzaNameRslt = mysqli_fetch_array($mauzaNameQry)) {
            echo $mauzaNameRslt['work_date'];
        }
    }
?>
```

UPDATE 3:

```
<?php
        $userId = 1; //ID to search for
        $ID = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM work_sheet where `mauza_id`='$userId'") or die(); //get ID and if it doesn't exist, exit
        $IdFromTable1 = $ID['moza_id']; // set the correct ID from table1
        $mauzaNameQry = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM moza_names where `mauza_id`='$IdFromTable1'") or die(); //check for table1's correct ID on table2
        echo $mauzaNameRslt['moza_name']; //echo the name from table1's ID
?>
```

Comment: there are two tables
1: work_sheet
2: moza_name
Table No 1 contains moza_id against each entery. On the basis of moza_id i am getting moza_name from Table 2 in loop. That is why i have written second query inside the while loop of Table 1.

Comment: The only thing that you put inside a while loop is `echo $rowss['work_date'];` because you didn't use any curly brackets.
If you don't surround the code in brackets, it only executes the next line as the loop.

Comment: it is not about the brackets, let me paste the code again
    while($rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)){
    echo $rowss['work_date'];
    $mauzaNameQry = mysqli_query($conn,"select moza_name from   moza_names where  mauza_id =1");
echo mysql_error();
$mauzaNameRslt = mysqli_fetch_array($mauzaNameQry);
echo $mauzaNameRslt['moza_name'];
}

Comment: timothy, i am simply trying to find names from 2nd table on the basis of id from 1st table. There is no need of nested loop in this case i guess.